# How to select a particular user role which could be flagged

Tags: 7, flags

There are two Roles:

- Authenticated
- Artist

I have created a flag with flag type "USER".
The flag is used so that the Authenticated Users can follow the Artists.

As the flag is type of user, an authenticated user can even follow another authenticated user.

How do I restrict the *flagging* to be applied only to the Artist? i.e the authenticated user can only follow an Artist and no user of any other role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by following below steps.

1. Create a view of type **User**.

   [image]
2. Add a relationship to Flag.

   [image]
3. Now add **Flags: Flag link** field + extra field you want to display
4. Finally add a FILTER CRITERIA i.e. **User: Roles** and select Artist user role.

Comment: 5. If you are putting this view on the Artist user profile page, you will want to add a contextual filter of user: uid. Then select provide default value and select User ID from url. **[see this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7YFtv.jpg)** **Note:** the view preview will become blank, don't worry, it will show up when you view your artist user page.

Comment: +1 for the solution. However, it does not cover the issue completely. How do you restrict _flagging_ of users of having roles other than _Artist_? I believe that it could be done by not showing the flag in links area or anywhere else and show it using a view on the artist profile page. In that case there needs to be an extra step which @NoSssweat has mentioned already.